# How to show dynamic List in PDFTable in iText

Tags: java, arraylist, pdf-generation, itext

I need your help in displaying the list of earnings which is retrieved from a database in a `PDFTable` in iText. The earnings will be having two columns which are: earnings_description and earnings_amount which are defined in a separate class called Earnings. The java code for retrieving them is:

```
List<Earnings> listEarnings = new ArrayList<Earnings>();

try{
    Connection con = Database.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Earnings");
    List<Earnings> listEarnings = new ArrayList<Earnings>();
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Earnings e = new Earnings();
                e.setEarningsDescription(rs.getString("Earning_description"));
                e.setEarningsAmount(rs.getString("Earning_amount"));
                listEarnings.add(e);
    }
catch(Exception e)){
System.out.println("Error");
}
```

However I tried to create a table to place the values under the headers, but I need some help. Below is the code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Earning Description"),font);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Earning Amount"),font);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(c1);
```

Now I need your assistant in adding the values under each header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , you didn't post your get methods for `earnings_description` & `earnings_amount`,

So assuming they are `getEarningsDescription()` & `getEarningsAmount()`, but adapt them according to your Earnings class :

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Earning Description"),font);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Earning Amount"),font);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.addCell(c1);

      // Here's how you adding the values 
for(int i=0;i<listEarnings.size();i++){



         String temp1 = listEarnings.get(i).getEarningsDescription();
         String temp2 =listEarnings.get(i).getEarningsAmount();


         if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
             temp="*"; // this fills the cell with * if the String is empty otherwise cell won't be created
         }

         if(temp2.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            temp2="*"; // this fills the cell with * if the String is empty otherwise cell won't be created
          }
table.addCell( temp1  ); // rows for first column
table.addCell(temp2);  // rows for seconds column

}
```

Note : don't forget to adapt those `getEarningsDescription()` & `getEarningsAmount()` accordingly